# query list a single row for each 2-uple fields

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.
table 1 user,
table 2 researchReq,
table 3 research

the `researchReq` table have some requirements that I use to check if a user fits to that specific research (like `min_age`, `max_age` and more) and a int field (num_of_days). the `research` table have a FK for researchReq, a FK for user,a date field and some more info. Among those users that fits to any `researchReq`, I need all those that the last `research` register was in more than `researchReq.num_of_days` and all those that dont have any `research` register.

e.g.

```
User
# | age
1 | 20
2 | 19
3 | 21

researchReq
# | min_age | max_age | num_of_days
1 | 15      | 25      | 20
2 | 25      | NULL    | 30

research
# | req_id | user_id | date
1 | 1      |  3      | 2014-08-20
2 | 1      |  3      | 2014-09-20
3 | 1      |  3      | 2014-10-20
4 | 1      |  2      | 2014-08-20
5 | 1      |  2      | 2014-09-20
```

In this case, all 3 users fits to the `researchReq #1`.

*min_age and max_age are nullable. If they are null, i need to disconsider when im checking if a user fits

```
user_id | researchReq_id | last
1       | 1              | null
2       | 1              | 30
```

user #1 dont have any register, so 'last' is null.

user #2 last register was in more than 20 days, so i list him and his interval.

Since the last register of `research` for user #3 dont have more than 20 days, i dont need him.

I tried something like this:

```
select ur.user_id, ur.req_id ,datediff(curdate(),ri.date) as last
from
     (
      select u.id as user_id, r.id as req_id, r.num_of_days as n_days
      from user u 
      join researchReq r
          on (r.min_age is null or datediff(curdate(),u.age) >= r.min_age)
          and (r.max_age is null or datediff(curdate(),u.age) <= r.max_age)
     ) as ur
left join research ri
    on ur.user_id = ri.user_id and ur.req_id = ri.req_id
having last > ur.n_days
```

But I got a problem. This query is listing all `research ri` register of each user and I need only the register with last date for each `ri.user_id` and `ri.req_id` (like a composite PK). I cant just use `group by user_id`, because it may have two or more distincts `ri.req_id`.

I just dont know how to do this.
Ty for any help and sorry for my bad english.

**@edit**

If a user have research with FK for 2 or more researchReq, this query will give me the min(datediff()) of all researchReq. I need it one by one, e.g:

```
user_id | researchReq_id | last
1       | 1              | null
2       | 1              | 30
2       | 2              | 15
```

query returns

```
user_id | researchReq_id | last
1       | 1              | null
2       | 1              | 15
2       | 2              | 15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your requirements, but this at least reproduces the answer that you were looking for with the data that you provided.

```
select u.user_id, r.id as researchReq_id, u.last from (
  select u.id as user_id, u.age, min(datediff(now(), date)) as last
      from user u 
      left join research r on r.user_id = u.id
      group by u.id
      having last is null or last > 20) as u
join researchReq r
on (r.min_age is null or u.age >= r.min_age)
          and (r.max_age is null or u.age <= r.max_age)
```

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e434c4/12)

Comment: In your edit, what's the difference between the first and the second set of results?

Comment: re edit.. the query return the min(datediff()) grouped by u.id, no matter what is researchReq_id. I know that it is the expected for this query, but I need something like min() which group by user_id AND researchReq_id.

Comment: To make things more clear.. I have a research system. In this system, users can create researchs with some requirements and an interval (used to know in how many days the research must be "reanswered"). I need a panel with all users that have any pending research to answer (if he never answered that research that he fits or if the last time he did have more than X days). again, sorry for my bad english

Comment: OMG! I didnt know that its possible to use group by X, Y.. this solved my problem. Im so sorry for bother.